# Prove that there exist six vertices in $S$ that are all adjacent to the same vertex $v$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Suppose that we have a set $S$ of $l$ vertices, each with degree at least $d$, and that $l > \frac{5n}{d}$. **Prove that there exist six vertices in $S$ that are all adjacent to the same vertex $v$, for some $v \in G$**

Comment: Add some context by sharing your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Is the graph $\left(S,E^S\right)$ an induced subgraph of $G$?

Comment: @ShinKim, you're right

Comment: What did you try? This problem is quite simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $S$ is a subgraph of $G$, its vertex set is a subset that of $G$, and so  $l\leq n$. But since $ld>5n\geq5l$, we have $d>5$ or $d\geq 6$. This means every vertex in $S$, which is also a vertex in $G$, has degree greater than or equal to $6$.

Comment: To OP, FYI: This answer is actually not a complete proof of the problem. You need to show further that there are six such vertices.

Comment: @BALISHBABA Think about the degree condition for the vertices in $S$...